# Converting dataset to numeric array changes value in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, dataset

I would be grateful for any insight on a quirk I'm trying to figure out in Matlab (I'm more used to R).  I've looked through the help pages and googled, but I can't find this exact problem.

I am working with data comprised of climate variables from several years.  I converted my numerical array to a dataset because I wanted to calculate means based on different categories of data.

```
% Make matrix then a dataset out of column vectors
data = [Year MO DD HR MM SS DecimalDate T_21m RH_21m P_bar_12m ws_21m wd_21m ustar_21m            z_L_21m precip_mm Td_21m vpd wet_b T_soil T_bole_pi T_bole_fi T_bole_sp Rppfd_in_ Rppfd_out     Rnet_25m_ Rsw_in_25 Rsw_out_2 Rlw_in_25 Rlw_out_2 T_2m T_8m RH_2m RH_8m h2o_soil co2_21m q];
header = {'Year', 'MO', 'DD', 'HR', 'MM', 'SS', 'DecimalDate', 'T_21m', 'RH_21m', 'P_bar_12m', 'ws_21m', 'wd_21m', 'ustar_21m', 'z_L_21m', 'precip_mm', 'Td_21m', 'vpd', 'wet_b', 'T_soil', 'T_bole_pi', 'T_bole_fi', 'T_bole_sp', 'Rppfd_in_', 'Rppfd_out', 'Rnet_25m_', 'Rsw_in_25', 'Rsw_out_2', 'Rlw_in_25', 'Rlw_out_2','T_2m', 'T_8m', 'RH_2m', 'RH_8m', 'h2o_soil', 'co2_21m',  'q'};
dataset1 = dataset({data,header{:}});
```

Here's what the first few rows look like to give you an idea of the dataset:

> > dataset1(1:5,:)

ans =

```
Year    MO    DD    HR    MM    SS    DecimalDate    T_21m    RH_21m    P_bar_12m    ws_21m    wd_21m    ustar_21m    z_L_21m
1998    11    1     0     15    0     305.01          1.9     86.9      70.27        NaN       279.8     NaN          NaN    
1998    11    1     0     45    0     305.03          1.9     86.9      70.27        NaN       279.8     NaN          NaN    
1998    11    1     1     15    0     305.05         2.03     86.9      70.27        NaN       108.2     NaN          NaN    
1998    11    1     1     45    0     305.07         2.03     86.9      70.27        NaN       108.2     NaN          NaN    
1998    11    1     2     15    0     305.09         1.75       87      70.27        NaN       255.7     NaN          NaN    


precip_mm    Td_21m    vpd    wet_b    T_soil    T_bole_pi    T_bole_fi    T_bole_sp    Rppfd_in_    Rppfd_out    Rnet_25m_
0            4.47      NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          0            NaN          -5.8     
0            4.47      NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          0            NaN          -5.8     
0            4.61      NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          0            NaN          -6.2     
0            4.61      NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          0            NaN          -6.2     
0            4.33      NaN    NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN          NaN          0            NaN          -6.6     


Rsw_in_25    Rsw_out_2    Rlw_in_25    Rlw_out_2    T_2m    T_8m    RH_2m    RH_8m    h2o_soil    co2_21m    q    quantum
NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN        0    night  
NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN        0    night  
NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN        0    night  
NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN        0    night  
NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN        0    night  


YearOrd    Day    YearNom
1998       305    1998   
1998       305    1998   
1998       305    1998   
1998       305    1998   
1998       305    1998
```

Next I added several columns that were ordinal so that I could use them as categories.  Here is an example of the code I used:

```
% Make a new data column based on year that is ordinal
y = min(Year(:));
Y = max(Year(:));
labels2 = num2str((y:Y)');
edges = y:Y+1;
dataset1.YearOrd = ordinal(dataset1.Year,labels2,[],edges);
```

Next I used the categories to calculate means, as follows:

```
statmean = grpstats(dataset1,{'YearOrd','Day','quantum'},'mean','DataVars',{'T_21m', 'RH_21m', 'P_bar_12m'});
```

And here is what the output looks like (notice how year is the first column):
ans =

```
                  YearOrd    Day    quantum    GroupCount    mean_T_21m    mean_RH_21m    mean_P_bar_12m
1998_305_night    1998       305    night      28             1.9579       87.067         70.151        
1998_305_day      1998       305    day        20              3.646       86.587         70.166        
1998_306_night    1998       306    night      28            0.76357       87.249         69.781        
1998_306_day      1998       306    day        20              2.258       86.669         69.668        
1998_307_night    1998       307    night      28             -2.735       80.785         69.862
```

Now comes the problem.  I want to be able to do further calculations with these means (e.g. divide all values by a number), and it seems that this is not permitted in Matlab's dataset format.  My solution was to convert the dataset 'statmean' into a numberical array using the 'double' command, as follows:

```
statTest = double(statmean);
```

However, this conversion from dataset to numeric array changes the values in my 'Year' column.  I printed out the first few rows of the numeric array to show this.  I suspect it has something to do with the levels in the previously ordinal Year column since 1998 was the first year.  However, I can't find information on how to change it.  Strangely, day of year (the second column) went through the transformation from ordinal to numeric correctly.  For the year, I know I could just add 1997, but I want to understand what is happening so I don't accidentally change other values when converting between numeric arrays and datasets.  Many thanks to all.

> > statTest(1:5,:)

ans =

```
1.0000  305.0000    1.0000   28.0000    1.9579   87.0671   70.1507
1.0000  305.0000    2.0000   20.0000    3.6460   86.5870   70.1660
1.0000  306.0000    1.0000   28.0000    0.7636   87.2493   69.7814
1.0000  306.0000    2.0000   20.0000    2.2580   86.6690   69.6680
1.0000  307.0000    1.0000   28.0000   -2.7350   80.7850   69.8621
```